# Can't I run maui blazor app without chrome in mobile app?

Tags: blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I am building an app using MAUI Blazor. There is one of the device which don't support Google Play Services, don't have System web view and Chrome.
When I try to run Blazor app on that device it throws me the below error.
[image]

Comment: And what exactly are you expecting?

Comment: Code a native Android app that uses [Android WebView](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview). (You can probably find example code somewhere.) Does that app work? If not, then it is not possible: the device has disabled the needed functionality.

Comment: The Blazor need to use the WebView. Here is the document about the [Maui Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/blazorwebview).